# Styled-Components: specify styles of children on parents hover

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a simple component
Here are 2 version of it - with and without styled-components:

### Without Styled Components

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="kid"></div>
</div>


#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#kid {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

#container:hover #kid{
    background: green;
}
```

### With Styled Components

```
const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
`;

const Kid = styled.div`
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
`;

<Container>
    <Kid />
</Container
```

How to implement the same on hover behaviour that was in the previous example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to handle hover in styled-components with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007060/best-way-to-handle-hover-in-styled-components-with-react)

Comment: Possible duplicate

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As of styled-components v2 you can interpolate other styled components to refer to their automatically generated class names. In your case you'll probably want to do something like this:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  &:hover ${Kid} {
    display: none;
  }
`
```

See [the documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) for more information!

> This is copy and pasted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007060/best-way-to-handle-hover-in-styled-components-with-react).

Comment: I was looking for this through the documentation and project's issues. Shouldn't it be part of the styledcomponents basic or advanced section instead of faq? Thanks for the good work.

Comment: its crazy to me how bass-ack-wards this is when we used to just have css descendent selectors before we over engineered our frontends with nonsense

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    &:hover #kid {
        background: green;
    }
`;

const Kid = styled.div`
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
`;

<Container>
    <Kid id="kid" />
</Container>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I removed all the ids and classes while using styled components

Comment: well try &:hover > * { background: green; }

Comment: Thanks any way. Are you going through fcc?

Comment: @ArslArsl yes, you can see my completed projects on my github

Comment: This doesn't look like proper solution. IDs cannot be used with components - there can be only one unique in DOM. And using * will target all elements so once you change structure eg. add one more div in middle, it will stop working - so best to target Kid specifically - like answer above does.

Answer (score 0):

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Parent = styled.div`
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
&:hover .btn {
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
`;

const button = styled.div`
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
`;
<Parent>
<button className="btn" />
</Parent>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).