# Selecting another part of the SVG based on hover isn't working

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have an SVG checkbox with a `circle` element surrounding a `polyline` element (the checkmark). Because the icon boundaries extend beyond the circle, using `&:hover` on the icon itself means you see the styles change when hovering outside the borders of the circle. So I want to only change styles on :hover over the circle itself. But I obviously need to change both the circle and the polyline on hover. I'm using styled-components.

I've tried everything I can think of to get the polyline to change on circle hover.

I began by trying something like:

```
& circle:hover circle, & circle:hover polyline { }
```

and several variations on this. Eventually I made the circle and polyline elements into styled components in order to more easily interpolate them. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007060/target-another-styled-component-on-hover?rq=1) I attempted this solution:

```
const Circle = styled.circle``;
const Polyline = styled.polyline``;

const Icon = styled.svg`
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;

  & ${Circle}, ${Polyline} {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: ${props => props.logged ? colors.secondary200 : colors.secondary400};

  & ${Circle}:hover {
    stroke: ${colors.secondary400};
    fill: ${colors.secondary400};
  }

  & ${Circle}:hover ${Polyline} {
    stroke: #fff;
    fill: ${colors.secondary400};
  }
```

But the polyline still doesn't change when hovering over the circle. I also tried nesting:

```
  & ${Circle}:hover {
    stroke: ${colors.secondary400};
    fill: ${colors.secondary400};

    & ${Polyline} {
      stroke: #fff;
      fill: ${colors.secondary400};
    }
  }
```

Nothing seems to be working. How should I be selecting this polyline?

**EDIT**: I realized based on styled-components documentation that it might be better to handle this styling in the Polyline styled-component, so I put the following together:

```
const Polyline = styled.polyline`
  pointer-events: none;
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: ${props => props.logged ? colors.secondary200 : colors.secondary400};

  ${Circle}:hover & {
    stroke: #fff;
    fill: ${colors.secondary400};
  }
`;
```

This still doesn't work, but `${Icon}:hover & { }` does work for some reason. I still can't use it because the `Icon`'s boundaries are outside the circle, but I am utterly at a loss for why the `Polyline` responds to hovering over the `Icon` but not the `Circle`. The `Circle` is definitely receiving a hover event because it applies its own `:hover` styles. Apparently Polyline is ignoring it though.

See JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mknerr67/tbe4hokx/2/#&togetherjs=1UQr6pIQua)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/x9j7ku8o/3/

The important bit being this:

```
const Circle = styled.circle`
  &:hover+${Polyline} {
    stroke: #fff;
    fill: #21ccbf;
  }
`;
```

The problem was that you were using the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) (by using a space between Circle and Polyline in the css selector), but Polyline isn't a descendant of Circle.

Polyline and Circle are **siblings**, so you must use one of the sibling combinators:
either the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) or the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator). I used the adjacent one, since Polyline and Circle are adjacent.

Important to note that the order matters: I use the combinator `&:hover+${Polyline}` in `Circle` because in your example's html, Circle comes before Polyline.

Comment: This worked great, thanks so much! Of course it ended up being a simple CSS issue and not some crazy React trickery.