# Target another component on hover using emotion-js

Tags: styled-components, emotion, css-in-js

I understand this is very similar to [Target another styled component on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007060/target-another-styled-component-on-hover)

However I would like to achieve the same effect with emotion-js

More specifically I am trying to recreate [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover) example using emotion styled components

Here is my code and what I have tried.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';

const Dropdown = styled.div`
  postition: relative;
  display: inline-block;
`;

const Button = styled.div`
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  &:hover {
    ${DropDownContent} {
      display: block;
    }
  }
`;

const DropDownContent = styled.div`
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
`;

const DropDownMenu = () => {
  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Button>Dropdown</Button>
      <DropDownContent>
        <Link to="/">Link 1</Link>
      </DropDownContent>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default DropDownMenu;
```

I would like the link to show up when I hover the button, but that is not working and I cannot figure out why

Answer (score 4):

There are three issues here.

1. You're referencing `DropdownContent` before you've defined it. Rearrange your code so that the `DropdownContent` declaration comes before the tagged template literals that use it and you should be good to go.
2. The resulting css selector (something like `button:hover .DropDownContent`) does not match your HTML document, where `DropDownContent` is a sibling of `Button`.
3. Your `position` property on `Dropdown` is misspelled.

With all three issues resolved, your code may look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';

const Dropdown = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
`;

const DropDownContent = styled.div`
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
`;

const Button = styled.div`
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  &:hover + ${DropDownContent} {
    display: block;
  }
`;

const DropDownMenu = () => {
  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Button>Dropdown</Button>
      <DropDownContent>
        <Link to="/">Link 1</Link>
      </DropDownContent>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default DropDownMenu;
```

Comment: Getting rid of the pseudo selector + worked for me and changing my markdown to wrap the Button around the DropDownContent. I think this makes sense because we want the DropDownContent style to change when hovering over the button and the links

Answer (score 0):

as @coreyward mentioned, rearrange the code.... and the

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";
```

and this will do the trick

This solution was already posted at [Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with babel-plugin-emotion error while using emotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61435282/component-selectors-can-only-be-used-in-conjunction-with-babel-plugin-emotion-er) by https://stackoverflow.com/users/165215/ijk