# Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with babel-plugin-emotion error while using emotion

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I have a styled component like

```
export const UL = styled.ul`
  list-style: none
`
export const Nav = styled.nav`
  ${UL}: {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }

  background-color: #222;
  padding: 0.35em 1.25em;


`
```

I ran the below command to add babel-plugin-emotion

```
npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-emotion
```

I get this error

[image]

what else do I need to do to get the plugin working with emotion?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out you can remove the module babel-plugin-emotion and use macros provided by [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/babel-macros).

Use the following import

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";
```

That's it and you are good to go.

Comment: what version of emotion does this apply to?

Comment: For me this didn't work presumably because I'm using typescript and not just javascript, and errors with: `Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with @emotion/babel-plugin.`

Comment: @Kzqai did you find any solutions for this issue ? Got this error when swiched CRA to Vite. 2 days wasted already.

Comment: @OliverIlmjärv None of my projects are really using emotion any more, (though I certainly would still try to use it, it's a good approach).