# emotion/styled nested class interpolation not working with linter or jest

Tags: typescript, styled-components, ts-jest, emotion

Targeting a child component `StyledHighlight`

```
<StyledButton>
  <StyledHighlight />
</StyledButton>
```

```
const StyledHighlight = styled.span`
    display: block;
`;

const StyledButton = styled.button`
    & > ${StyledHighlight} {
        display: none;
    }
`;
```

---

Getting a lint error similar to this:

```
Invalid type "StyledComponent<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>, Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>, "contextMenu" | ... 253 more ... | "css">, object>" of template literal expression  @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions
```

Also, our jest test is no longer passing, it doesn't see the inherited `display: none` and thinks the display is always 'block', though our storybook shows it rendering correctly.

Interestingly, `background-color` does seem to propagate (when using another method `span[data-testid="styled-highlight"]`, not sure about the class interpolation), but still not `display`

Does anyone know what I might be missing with emotion/styled, typescript, and jest?

I haven't seen much information about this online, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41010688/1487102) seems to validate that this is a legitimate way to target a child